# How to open a 32" Philips CRT TV for service

Tags: repair, tv

I have an old and faithful (well, until today) 32" Philips **CRT** TV (32pw9309) that was purchased on 2004 and served me very well since then. Today, while the kids were watching a DVD, we heard a "pop" sound and the screen went blank. The blue power led started blinking. I can turn the TV off and on, but after a few secs the led starts blinking again.

So, assuming that the sound was of a blown capacitor, I decided to open up the beast and try to locate that cap. Flipping it on the screen side, I unscrewed the 6 screws and tried to pull the cover up. The problem seems to be that there are plastic locks at the topside of the screen, which I cannot release, so the cover won't fully open.

**Any idea how can I open the cover for servicing the TV?**

[TV on Philips site](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/dcbint/cpindex.pl?tmplt=Philips&scy=CH&slg=ENG&cat=TELEVISIONS_CA&sct=OTHER_TELEVISIONS_SU&grp=SOUND_AND_VISION_GR&session=20110611050454_66.249.72.115&ctn=32PW9309/12&mid=Link_ProductInformation&hlt=Link_ProductInformation)

[image]

(If you think there is a better site for this question, please let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always best to start with a service manual, if you can find one, to see the 'right' way to go about fixing things. Philips is fortunately pretty good when it comes to service manuals.

Step 1: [This link](http://english.electronica-pt.com/electronics-search.php?find=32PW9309) tells you that the chassis model for your set is "EM5.2E AA".

Step 2: [This link](http://elektrotanya.com/philips_chassis_em5.2e-aa_sm.pdf/download.html) has the service manual (and many others BTW).

Step 3: The manual says:

> Four openings (1) can be found at the top. The openings are very small (2). Note: Some sets only have the two inner openings.
>
> Underneath every opening there is a clip. Push this clip down with a very thin piece of metal (3), until you hear a click. Caution: do not use a screwdriver, this will damage the
> cabinet.

[image]

(I personally like YouTube disassembly videos combined with the service manual to get a 'feel' of how to do things right without breaking stuff unnecessarily.)

Comment: Great, thanks. I searched for the service manual but could not find it. I assumed that such old sets will be hard-to-find. YouTube gave no results either.